# Python code to use NTLM authentication for SingleSignOn particularly in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ntlm, aws-lambda, aws-cli

Is there a way to create saml authentication for AWS from NTLM using Python. Quint Van Deman has talked in length about Federated API access using saml below:

https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/blog/author/Quint+Van+Deman

However, I need the Single Sign On to use NTLM as its already integrated with ADFS.

Comment: You might want to look at Auth0 for a 3rd party solution